# $state.go() change the url but not change the html content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am new in angular and ionic and after successful login (by laravel api),i am trying to redirect to the another page , now the problem is that the url is successfully changed but the content of that page is not loaded, and i see some related question on this site they offer to try event.preventDefault(); but that is not working for me.

```
.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,api,$state){
 $scope.doLogin = function(){
  api.login.userLogin(data).then(function(res){
  if(res.data.status == 'success'){
    event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('app.chat');
  }else{
    console.log('sorry');
  }
});
```

and the state which i want to load is

```
 .state('app.chat', {
url: "/chat",
views: {
  'tab-chat': {
    templateUrl: "templates/demo.html",
    controller: 'ChatlistCtrl'
  }
}
```

my demo.html code

```
`<ion-content ng-controller="ChatlistCtrl" ng-init="$index = 0">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="value in responce">
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-click="null" type="item-text-wrap">
    <h2>{{responce[$index].name}}</h2>
     <p>This is a demo title</p>
     <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
     <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ngclick="remove({{responce[$index].id}})">
  Delete
</ion-option-button>
```

`

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there errors in console

Comment: no there is not any console and api request id success.

Comment: did u try it without `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: yup tried but same problem

Comment: share all your routes pls and your base html

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead of your code.

```
.state('app.chat', {
url: "/chat",
templateUrl: "templates/demo.html",
controller: 'ChatlistCtrl'

});
```

if not works,plz add your demo.html in your question.

Comment: appreciate your reply #raj peer .but your code is also not working for me.. i explain the problem in depth. look i got the successful response from the api and successfully got the url in browser's address bar . but the problem is html not loaded after that ,if i reload that same page then it loads the page. please check the updated question for the code of demo.html

Comment: lets try this: change state name "chat" instead of "app.chat". and your html page will load. if you want to test, comment your demo.html code, then add only one div like <div>Hiiiii</div>.. if you still got problem, plz let know.

Comment: already try that trick .. but now it solve the problem . that was my mistake i call it in <ion-modal-view> ........</ion-modal-view> . but i have to load it in <ion-content> ........ </ion-content>. but thanks for your help